# Elastic search calculation with data from different indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

Good day, everyone. I have a lit bit strange case of using elastic search for me.

There are two different indexes, each index contain one data type.

- First type contains next important for this case data:

  - **keyword (text,keyword)**,
  - URL (text,keyword)
  - position (number).
- Second type contains next data fields:

  - **keyword (text,keyword)**
  - numberValue (number).

**I need to do next things:**

```
1.Group data from the first ind by URL
2.For each object in group calculate new metric (metric A) by next simple formula: position*numberValue*Param
3.For each groups calculate sum  of elements metric A we have calculated on stage 1
4.Order by desc result groups by sums we have calculated on stage 3
5.Take some interval of result groups.
```

Param - param, i need to set for calculation, this is not in elastic.

That is not difficult algorithm, but data in different indices, and i don`t know how to do it fast, and i prefer to do it on elastic search level.

I don`t know how to make effective data search or pipeline of data processing which can help me to implement this case.
I use ES version 6.2.3 if it is important. 
Give me some advice, please, how can i implement this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

By reading 2. you seem to assume *keyword* is some sort of primary key. Elasticsearch is not an RDB and can only reason over one document at a time, so unless *numberValue* and *position* are (indexed) fields of the same document you can't combine them.

The rest of the items seem to be possible to achieve with the help of [Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations.html)